# Zipcode belongs to only one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i´ve got these tables

```
create table Town (
   Town varchar(50)     not null,
   Province varchar(50) not null,
 constraint PK_Town primary key (Town)
 )

create table Streetpart (
    Zipcode varchar(6)   not null,
    Town varchar(50)     not null,
    Street varchar(50)   not null,
 constraint PK_Streetpart primary key (ZipCode),
 constraint FK_Streetpart foreign key (Town) references TOWN(Town)
)

create table ADRES (
      Zipcode      varchar(6) not null,
      Housenumeber int        not null,
 constraint PK_ADRES primary key (Zipcode, Housenumber),
 constraint FK_ADRES foreign key (Zipcode) references Streetpart(Zipcode)
)
```

How can i be sure that only *Zipcode* belongs to *Street*,*Housenumber* and *Town*.

```
For example:
  Street         Housenumber   Zipcode Town
  Port du Louvre 12            1234AB  Paris
  Port du Louvre 12            5432PQ  Paris
```

is not allowed.

thanx for help.

Comment: How do you know which one is the correct one?

Comment: And another thing: Using an integer column for the house number will not work in most countries since there are many combined numbers like 'Castle Rd 33b'

Comment: And where exactly, do zip codes have to be different for every single address?

Comment: sample data must not exists in database, preventing

Comment: And there are zip codes longer than 6 characters in the world
And be aware that town names quite often have different names in different languages. E.g. Geneva in English, Genève in French, Genf in German etc. Maybe it would be better if you would describe what you intend to do and we then advise on a better data structure.

Comment: This Schema is wacky nonsense. Why would you have a table with just `zip` and `housenumber`. That makes no sense. Like: "Here's a list of house numbers that reside in this zipcode... I have no idea which street these relate to, but that wasn't in the spec" This should all be on table called "Address". You have over-normalized your data and now you are dealing with the consequences.

Comment: You have over normalized and lost one of the main benefits of normalization all at once. For example you have the string Town as the primary key. Then you have to repeat that value in every other table. UGH!!! In your schema you can't have that town name in more than one province. This is a train wreck.